# Forgot password page throws error, after Spree deployed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, spree

I set up the smtp mailer, sent the **test mail successfully**.
Log in everything works fine, but when i try the **forgot password function**, i get a

> We are sorry something went wrong.

screen.

Spree version: 1.3.2
Rails: Rails 3.2.13

This is the /log/production.log

```
Started GET "/user/password/new" for 81.182.63.72 at 2013-03-24 10:18:28 +0000
Processing by Spree::UserPasswordsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-78342b5fa7c5/app/views/spree/user_passwords/new.html.erb within spree/layouts/spree_application (3.1ms)
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/shared/_search.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/shared/_nav_bar.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered spree/shared/_header.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered spree/shared/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spree_core-1.3.2/app/views/spree/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 17.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
Started POST "/user/password" for 81.182.63.72 at 2013-03-24 10:18:30 +0000
Processing by Spree::UserPasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g4fttrrEVPehE6usYfWupw+b8J3F4Y+79FBTqNWpD+I=", "user"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Új jelszót kérek"}
  Rendered /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree_auth_devise-78342b5fa7c5/app/views/spree/user_mailer/reset_password_instructions.text.erb (0.8ms)

Sent mail to example@gmail.com (92ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 242ms

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
  /home/gwuix2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how, but now it works. Didn't do anything about it.
Mabye issue was with SMTP mailer.